# Installed TestNG is not displayed in Run configuration

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I have installed TestNG from Eclipse MarketPlace. I've checked it in Installed Software:[image]

However, when I open Run As, there is not TestNG but Java Application and Maven. When I go to Window -> Show View -> Other -> Java folder, there it not TestNG.

I found a similar question: [TestNG not showing up in preferences- JDK 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52717511/testng-not-showing-up-in-preferences-jdk-1-8) but it hasn't been solved until today.

Also I've got some error in Error Log but I have no idea if it's related to TestNG:
[image]

Would someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you.

I also checked this question:
[TestNG option not showing in RunAs option in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384826/testng-option-not-showing-in-runas-option-in-eclipse)

The version of Eclipse is 4.27.0 and JDK is 18.0.1.1

Comment: Is TestNG plugin is enabled in Eclipse ?

Comment: Yes, I followed these steps: https://www.guru99.com/install-testng-in-eclipse.html and at Step 8, I can't find it in Other -> Java folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I've solved the problem. After uninstalling TestNG, I noticed that "TestNG P2 Feature" remained in Installed Software. I manually uninstalled it, then re-installed TestNG from Eclipse Marketplace. Now I can see TestNG in Window -> Show View -> Other -> Java folder. I still don't know what caused this problem, but this is how I fixed it.